# No keydown event raised with specific preceding key combo held

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, keydown

```js
    window.onkeydown = function(e){
     console.log(e.key);
    };
```

If I open the chrome console, click on the document and hold they keyboard keys <kbd>q</kbd>, then <kbd>w</kbd>, then <kbd>e</kbd> without releasing any, when I subsequently press <kbd>p</kbd> I can see that an event is raised and `p` is printed to the console.

If I do the same with <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, and <kbd>d</kbd>, I do not see an event raised for <kbd>p</kbd>.

What is the problem here? Is anyone else able to replicate this?

Comment: I can replicate this in Chrome.

Comment: Its screwing up my game.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Are you using a wireless keyboard?

Comment: No. A regular wired USB keyboard.

Comment: I am being advised that this is a hardware problem, and that different hardware will allow a different amount of keys [not including some like shift and ctrl] to be pressed at the same time...

Comment: That doesn't seem to apply here since the same amount of keys are being pressed in both of your test cases. The difference isn't in the amount of keys being pressed, but in which keys are pressed.

Comment: If the keyboard for some reason at a hardware level categorises some keys differently, it may weight some differently to others.